# Phpmyadmin weird characters after ajax post

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I insert some data from a php form to the database. When I enter greek characters the database shows strange characters.

I have in my HTML `charset="utf-8"`
I tried decoding the post values and then from strange characters it gives me ????

```
$.ajax({
   url:postURL,
   method:"POST",             
   data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
   type: 'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
     i=1;
     var spot = document.getElementById('spot_name').value;
     window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url("index.php/Spot_preview/spot_preview/");?>"+spot;

   }
  });
```

php

```
foreach ($_POST["date"] as $key => $date) {
    $dur =$_POST['spot_duration'];
    $cat = $_POST['category'][$key];
    $price = $dur * $cat;
    $spot_name = ($_POST['spot_name']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO spot(spot_duration,spot_type,spot_name,spot_link,customer_name,spot_date,spot_show,spot_time,spot_price,spot_category) VALUES ('".$_POST['spot_duration']."','".$_POST['spot_type']."','".$spot_name."','".$_POST['file_name_helper']."','".$_POST['customer_name']."','".$date."','".$_POST['show'][$key]."','".$_POST['time'][$key]."',$price,'".$_POST['category'][$key]."')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: what is the collation set to?

Comment: @comphonia utf8-unicode-ci

Comment: try changing it to a greek_general_ci in the phpmyadmin settings

Comment: I did, still getting weird characters. If I dont use ajax and I just submit the form through php, the data are stored correctly. So I assume it has to do with the ajax post and not the database

Comment: if you're serializing the form as JSON you would have to parse the data and build an SQL query from it. can't help without seeing the back-end code too

Comment: I added the backend code. I also tried to unserialize the post values but still it gives weird characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your contentType to support different charset:

```
dataType: 'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

---

**EDIT:** .. I've **tried and tested** it myself and found that there is no issues with ajax request at all and it sends the data perfectly fine but the issue is on the server side upon receiving.

You have to set the php header like this in your method:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

I've sent this text `ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΛλΜμΝν` and received and echoed it correctly after setting the header with charset utf-8.

Comment: It doesn't send the data if I add those lines

Comment: @Spy .. its `dataType` not `type` .. try again and show me your new code.

Comment: I edited the code. I added the lines and it only sends the data if I remove the contentType line. But still it saves them faulty in the db

Comment: What about echoing them before saving them to the database, is it faulty as well? .. and tell me if the headers from ajax post are correct.

Comment: When I add your lines it doesn't make the redirection. I can't echo them

Comment: I'll try it myself and add a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `serializeArray()` to create a JSON from post data. added a console.log for debugging.

```
 $('.submitBtn').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var sdata = $('#add_name').serializeArray();
     console.log(fdata);
   $.ajax({
       url:'',
       method:"POST",             
       data:fdata,
       type: 'json',
       success:function(data)
       {
         i=1;
         var spot = document.getElementById('spot_name').value;
         window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url("index.php/Spot_preview/spot_preview/");?>"+spot;
       }
      });
 })
```